# saving a bunch of models at once

Tags: backbone.js

I have about ~150 "models" which I would like, with one click, to save in DB (slimphp->mysql).

What would be better solution:

- to iterate through the each model and make http request for each model, or
- to save entire collection at once with one http request

**this**

```
 var newModel = App.request("needModel:new");
 $.when(newModel ).done(function(model){
   _.each(arrayOfModels, function () {
     var modelCloned = model;
     modelCloned.save(modelData)
   });
});
```

**or this**

```
  var somecollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: somemodel,       
    url: "someurl",     
    syncCollection: function() {
      Backbone.sync('create', this);
    }       
  });

somecollection.syncCollection(arrayOfModels);
```

Comment: uhmmm... why prefer `n` requests (`n = 150`) over one? it's a no-brainer

Comment: what is wrong with the question? why it has been downvoted?.. anyway thank you for you answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sync the entire collection at once. Firing off 150+ requests is not a fun idea.